# How to get specific value from responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with an api after submitting data i am getting response from which i need a specific value of lead_id

### here is the jquery ajax response that i get after success:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, 
setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )
pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ ( obj )
readyState: 4
responseText: "done{"lead_id":1511313,"phone":"123456789","message":"Data uploaded successfully"}"
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )
```

Now i am able to alert data of responseText but how to get specific value from it.

### Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url:"check.php?a=api",
    data:datas,
    success:function(res)
    {
        var aa=res.responseText;
    alert(aa);
        console.log(res);
    },
    error:function(res)
    {

        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

### Here is the check.php through which i am sending data to the api

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_GET['a'])
{
    $fname=$_GET['F_Name'];
    $mname=$_GET['M_Name'];
    $lname=$_GET['L_Name'];
    $age=$_GET['Age'];
    $mobile=$_GET['MobileNumber'];
    $email=$_GET['EmailID'];
    $city=$_GET['City'];
    $state=$_GET['State'];

    $url="http://apiurl/api/vendor/upload?cp_id=565&v_id=117&c_id=13&first_name=".$fname."&last_name=".$lname."&email=".$email."&phone=".$mobile;
   }
$handle=fopen($url,"r");
if($handle)
{
    while(!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer=fgets($handle,4096);
    echo $buffer;
}
}
fclose($handle);
```

i need the value of lead_id

Comment: `responseText` is a string or object?
`done` is weird even it's `JSON` string. you need to remove it to make  `responseText` a valid `JSON` string

Comment: `"done{"lead_id"` looks strange. What is the value of `res.responseText`?

Comment: @showdev when i alert res.responseText i get this done{"lead_id":1511313,"phone":"123456789","message":"Data uploaded successfully"}

Comment: Hi @denny you can use JSON.stringify to convert this object to json string and after that use JSON.parse to convert into object format.

Comment: I don't recognize the format of the response. It doesn't appear to be a valid representation of an object or function. Are you in control of `check.php`? How is the response generated from that file?

Comment: @showdev added the check.php in the question

Comment: The response of the API might not be JSON. It seems like it starts with the string "done" and then outputs an object. What do you get if you access that URI directly, like in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this and if you face error, share.

```
var str = responseText.replace('done', '');
str = str.replace('}"', '}');
var data = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(data.lead_id);
```

Comment: getting this error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0

Comment: comment the last two lines and add this line:
`console.log(str);`

Share what do you have printed in console

Comment: It might be worth finding out why the response starts with `done`. That seems odd.

Comment: yes, there is something wrong in your ajax call.
Let me check that.

Comment: @TayyabRazaq this is what i get from console.log(str) 
 
done{"lead_id":1511458,"phone":"9999836888","message":"Data uploaded successfully"}

Comment: Good, Updated the answer, please try now.

Comment: there are some issues in php that might cause this request to fail, like when the file is too big, the request will only return partial of the data, because you are echoing in a while loop, which will return the first data but discard the remaining data.

Answer (score -1):

Change responseText data with this.

```
 responseText :{"lead_id":1511313,"phone":"123456789","message":"Data uploaded successfully"};
 console.log(responseText.lead_id);
```